# ReactJS hooks can't update state

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-hooks

I have react app with pull values from database in every 10 seconds with express backend.

Problem is in my dashboard some values don't rendering, they just change when I refresh the page.

For example, I get the 10 value from database includes Date_time. In Dashboard I set all 10 values as state. Time is top of the page and update itself every ten seconds.
I send as a props other 9 state `history={props.history} site_informations={x} channelName_coverted={(x.ChannelName).replace("_"," ")}`  as a props like that.

When check the these 9 values, they are not rendering realtime.

I really need help.
Sorry for the complexity of the code, I'm new to react.

**SOLVED**
Thanks for @Abhay Sehgal  and @szczocik.

The reason of this problem is using useEffect in functional component for updating props.

UseEffect executed once when the component is mounted, so using just `props.value` is necessary for updating in functional component.

Comment: In Home.js file jsx contains x like x.ChannelName, but it's not defined, 2nd in Deposits.js you can directly use values through props instead of storing them in state as you're not updating them, just rendering

Comment: Oh , I am so sorry . I made a mistake writing the code. 
This is a map function actually, I edited

Comment: As @AbhaySehgal said, instead of assigning the props to the state in your Deposits component, just use them directly. The use effect with an empty array as dependency array is only executed once when the component is mounted. You could add props to the dependency array, to run it every time the props change